# Why does Promisification fail for some methods but not all?

Tags: bluebird, jsonix

The `jsonix` library does not follow the `first argument must be an error` convention so I decided to use bluebird and promisify it like so:

```
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      try {
        unmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlResponse,
          function (unmarshalled) {
            ...
            resolve(unmarshalled);
          });
      }
      catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
```

But this hangs indefinitely! Whereas if I simply save the `xmlResponse` to a file and then process it with a different method: `unmarshalFile` ... the promisification seems to work just fine!

```
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      try {
        unmarshaller.unmarshalFile('test1.xml',
          function (unmarshalled) {
            ...
            resolve(unmarshalled);
          });
      }
      catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
```

So my question is why would promisification fail for one method but not another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at [the code for jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/33ff2866ef384e6abf049c72e2b53841b51344f4/scripts/src/main/javascript/org/hisrc/jsonix/Jsonix/Binding/Unmarshaller.js#L9), I don't see any callback function for `.unmarshalString()` and looking at the implementation, there's nothing async in the implementation and nothing that calls a callback.  It just returns the answer directly.  So, the function is synchronous, not async and returns its value directly as a return value.

For reference, `.unmarshalURL()` and `.unmarshalFile()` do accept the callback and do have an async implementation - `.unmarshalString()` is just different.

So, you don't need to use promises with `unmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlResponse)` at all.  You could just return the straight value:

```
return unmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlResponse);
```

If you want to wrap it in a promise for consistency of interface among all three methods, you can do this:

```
try {
    return Promise.resolve(unmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlResponse));
} catch(err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
}
```

Or, you can use Bluebird's `Promise.method()` to wrap it for you:

```
return Promise.method(unmarshaller.unmarshalString.bind(unmarshaller, xmlResponse));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

`unmarshalURL` and `unmarshalFile` are async (and have to be) but `unmarshalString` or `unmarshalDocument` are not async (and don't have to be).

Comment: Thank you for sharing, now I just feel ... dum da dum dum DUMB!